# How to replace sub-query by joins?

Tags: mysql

How can i get rif of theses subqueries ?

(all tables have columns Created and LastEdited as timestamps)

```
table Process
 - ID
 - Title

table ProcessHistory
 - ID
 - ProcessID
 - HistoryID

table History
 - ID
 - Title (new, open, closed etc.)
```

When i try to get a list of processes with cols of the last status title i do:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Process.*, History.Title AS HistoryTitle, History.ID AS HistoryID
FROM `Process`
LEFT JOIN ProcessHistory AS ProcessHistory ON Process.ID=ProcessHistory.ProcessID
LEFT JOIN History AS History ON HistoryID=ProcessHistory.HistoryID
WHERE History.ID = (
    SELECT HistoryID FROM ProcessHistory 
    WHERE ProcessID=Process.ID 
    ORDER BY ProcessHistory.ID DESC LIMIT 1
)
GROUP BY Process.ID
ORDER BY Process.ID DESC LIMIT 0, 100
```

When i try to get a list filtered by a specific status
(Where the latest HistoryID is 1 - "all open Processes")

```
SELECT DISTINCT Process.*, History.Title AS HistoryTitle, History.ID AS HistoryID
FROM `Process`
LEFT JOIN ProcessHistory AS ProcessHistory ON Process.ID=ProcessHistory.ProcessID
LEFT JOIN History AS History ON HistoryID=ProcessHistory.HistoryID
WHERE History.ID=(
    SELECT HistoryID FROM ProcessHistory 
    WHERE HistoryID =1   
    AND ProcessID=Process.ID ORDER BY ProcessHistory.ID DESC LIMIT 1
)
GROUP BY Process.ID
ORDER BY Process.ID DESC LIMIT 0, 100
```

For performance reasons i want to get rid of theses subqueries?
How can i replace the subquery?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: A sqlfiddle created and loaded by you would go a long way to help us to help you. Note: loaded doesn't mean fully loaded. It might mean 5 to 10 rows of data for each table.

Comment: Here the sql fiddle:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3d9001/1

Comment: Is it really the performance bottleneck or is this premature or perhaps even unneccasary optimization?

Comment: This seems strange: `SELECT HistoryID FROM ProcessHistory WHERE HistoryID =1 ...`. Why select HistoryID if you already know that `HistoryID=1`?

Comment: Please fix the complaints raised in comments and answers, delete this question, and start over.  A "bounty" should not be given for mistakes.

Comment: @RickJames Maybe a bounty is in order when the attention received so far has been from those not really interested in trying to understand and actually answer the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll still need to make another select to filter out the rest of the process history, but you should use a [derived table](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mysql/article.php/3914401/Use-Derived-Tables-in-Your-MySQL-Queries-to-Improve-Database-Performance.htm) instead of a subquery, like this [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3d9001/55/0):

```
SELECT Process.*, History.Title AS HistoryTitle
FROM Process
JOIN (
  SELECT ProcessID, max(HistoryID) as HistoryID
  FROM ProcessHistory
  GROUP BY ProcessID
) PH ON PH.ProcessID = Process.ID
JOIN History ON History.ID = PH.HistoryID
ORDER BY Process.ID DESC LIMIT 0, 100
```

As Himanshu Patel pointed out, your query to "get a list filtered by a specific status (Where the latest HistoryID is 1 - "all open Processes")" will not produce the desired effect. It will simply return all processes that have a HistoryID of 1. See this [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3d9001/57/0).

Instead, you want to use a derived table to get those latest process history ids, join them with the processes, and filter on the history ids like this [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3d9001/59/0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT Process.*, History.Title AS HistoryTitle
FROM Process
JOIN (
  SELECT ProcessID, max(HistoryID) as HistoryID
  FROM ProcessHistory
  GROUP BY ProcessID
) PH ON PH.ProcessID = Process.ID
JOIN History ON History.ID = PH.HistoryID
WHERE PH.HistoryID = 1
ORDER BY Process.ID DESC LIMIT 0, 100
```

An alternative approach would be to create a view that filters the ProcessHistory table to the latest history per process and join on that. YMMV, but in some cases, performance can be improved that way.

Answer (score 3):

Query you posted not give proper result as per `ORDER BY ProcessHistory.ID DESC LIMIT 1`
Try below query as per result of your query

```
 SELECT DISTINCT p.*, h.Title AS HistoryTitle,h.ID AS  HistoryID
FROM
Process p JOIN ProcessHistory ph ON p.ID=ph.ProcessID and ph.HistoryID=1 
JOIN History h ON h.ID=ph.HistoryID
GROUP BY p.ID
ORDER BY p.ID DESC LIMIT 0, 100;
```

Here the sql fiddle:
[sql fiddle link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3d9001/41)

If you want other result then comment.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM Process AS p
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT ph.ProcessID, ph.HistoryID, h.Title AS HistoryTitle
  FROM ProcessHistory AS ph
  JOIN History AS h ON ph.HistoryID = h.ID
  WHERE h.ID = 1
) AS phh ON p.ID = phh.ProcessID
ORDER BY p.ID DESC LIMIT 100
```

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Due to the actual subquery, used to get "last" row related to each "process", you can neither convert it to a JOIN nor can you use it as a separate query to set a session variable.